# What stack are they using? Pitch, Whimsical

Tags: mongodb, api, clojure, stack

I'm trying to figure what stack pitch.com or whimsical.com are using. They have one thing in common. They're using Clojure and all their API responses are looking like this:

**Pitch**
https://document-sync-4-prod.api.pitch.com/fetch-objects

[image: Pitch]

**Whimsical**
https://whimsical.com/api/items.sync

[image: Whimsical]

Is this something related how Clojure works or are they maybe using MongoDB?

Why is this API response looking so weird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like these services are using [transit format](https://github.com/cognitect/transit-format) in their APIs.

It is used for communication between services (or backend and frontend). It is not related to the database they are using and it is also available for other programming languages. However, Clojure engineers often prefer this to other formats due to the good language support (see [transit-clj](https://github.com/cognitect/transit-clj) and [transit-cljs](https://github.com/cognitect/transit-cljs)).

Comment: Ah very interesting, thanks for the details.